# Making ListPickerItems strings or geting the x:name of the SelectedIndex()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have 5 static values I would like to populate in a ListPicker control, the one that ships with the Silverlight tool-kit. I would like to be able to create these in Xaml and then reference them. I tried using ListPickerItems but the ToString() method does not return the name (which I essentially need). Is there a way of getting the x:name of these items or converting them to strings so I can get a string value back from the selected index.

These values will never change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `ListPickerItems` in xaml, and set each one's `DataContext` to the value you want.  or some people use the `Tag` field for holding some other data too.